# Floyd's Algorithm: Array Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, pointers, null, integer

I keep getting a null pointer exception. However, the reason eludes me. Can someone help?

EDIT: I am using an Integer[][] array to represent null values as "infinity" symbols as floyd's algorithm is represented on paper

```
private static Integer[][] floyd( Integer[][] a ) {
    int n = a.length;

    for( int k = 0; k < n; k++ ) {
        System.out.println( "D(" + (k+1) + ") =" );

        for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {              
            for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
                // The below line throws a null pointer exception and I don't know why
                a[i][j] = Math.min( a[i][j],  a[i][k] + a[k][j] );
            }
        }

        print2DArray( a );
    }

    return a;
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the call of `floyd(a)`.

Comment: one of your elements of a is null.  I don't understand why you're asking.  If you understand what a null pointer is, I don't see why this isn't obvious.  Or have you forgotten that we have no idea what is in 'a'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what's in your input array, you're likely to be auto-unboxing a null, which causes the null pointer exception.  If you declare the array as an `int[][]` instead of an `Integer[][]`, you won't get this.